# creating spring bean

Tags: spring

Is there a way to write a Spring bean in XML so that it uses constructor which doesn't need an argument.
For instance:

```
public class CronSchedule {
    public CronSchedule() throws Exception {
        SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        Scheduler sched = sf.getScheduler();
        JobDetail jd = new JobDetail("job1", "group1", CronJob.class);
        CronTrigger ct = new CronTrigger("cronTrigger", "group2", "0 * * * * ?");
        sched.scheduleJob(jd, ct);
        sched.start();
    }
}
```

Should I use `<constructor-arg />` or I should write just bean tags without it ?

```
<bean name="cronSchedule" class="com.lastogat.CronSchedule">
        <constructor-arg />
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't need to define the constructor-arg it will pick up the constructor as there is no other.

But I would suggest to inject those dependencies you create in the constructor defining them as beans in spring rather than creating them as new instances.

Comment: @pedromarce, I hope you don't mind me editing your answer. I just threw in the XML that you are referring to. Feel free to rollback if you want.